# 'strong chance' or 'strong possibility'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, meaning-in-context, esl

'there is a strong chance that our team will win.'

**or**

'there is a strong possibility that our team will win.'?

i think the latter seems more suitable.

thoughts?

Comment: @Rattler for the sentence, which is from an exercise i got

Comment: I would go for the first one, it feels more natural to me and I've used it quite a lot.

Comment: Between the two, I would choose *chance*; however, I think **high probability** (also replacing *strong*) could be better than either, depending on the actual context and level of formality required.

Comment: You wouldn't be going wrong with either option -- there is little difference between the two. Personally, I would use *high probability*, as suggested by @JasonBassford, but in doing so I would be expressing a high degree of confidence that my team would win, perhaps higher than that implied by either of your two examples. I would also drop *that*.